# When searching by state, sort option defaults to "Date Listed" even though results are sorted by "Proximity to Location"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

Sorting is broken for search results on the Careers site:

First, search for all jobs on Careers in a certain area (e.g. Kansas).

On the results page, the sort option defaults to 'Date Listed'.  However, the results themselves are actually sorted by 'Proximity to Location' (the results don't change if the 'Proximity' option is selected - they *do* change if 'Date Listed' is re-selected).

It's not a big deal (oh gosh, *two* clicks instead of one), but I wanted to...inform someone?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log in using GMail
2. Search for all jobs in a specific state (no job title keyword, only location)

Returned results are in "Proximity to ..." sort order, while sort option combo box shows "Date Posted".

To get the actual "Date Posted" order, you have to first select a different sort order, then re-select "Date Posted"

Comment: No worries. I believe you. I think I know what's up. If you search by state, your error occurs. If you search by city, it works like expected.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this last night.  The default sort order when no sort order was specified was determined inside the function that builds the query for jobs.  We cache the results of these queries for a short time and we were not storing the selected sort in the cache.  Now we are.

Comment: Are you sure this is already fixed on the live site? It is still clearly sorted wrong for the query I'm performing. Either that or the site considers half my country the same distance away :)